Relation of endianness to assembly conversion of size in C
Please note that the below is adapted from Problem 3.4 of Bryant and O'Hallaron's text (CSAPP3e). I have stripped away everything but my essential question.
Context: we are looking at a x86-64/Linux/gcc combo wherein ints are 4 bytes and chars are considered signed (and, of course, 1 byte). We are interested in writing the assembly corresponding to conversion of an int to a char which, at a high level, we know arises from performing truncation.
They present the following solution:
movl (%rdi), %eax            // Read 4 bytes
movb %al, (%rsi)             // Store low-order byte

My question is whether we can change the movl to a movb since, after all, we are only using a byte in the end. My concern with this suspicion is that there might be some endian-dependence with the read, and we might somehow be getting the high bits if our processor/OS is in little-endian mode. Is this suspicion correct, or would my change work no matter what?
I would try this out but 1) I am on a Mac with Apple silicon and 2) even if my suspicion worked, I couldn't be sure if this sort of thing was implementation-dependent.

Just movb would not be a good idea. Writing the whole EAX (and hence RAX) avoids any shenanigans with partial registers. Using the instruction form that extents from byte to dword would be more appropriate: movzbl (%rdi), %eax.

You can use movb (%rdi), %al without much of a change in meaning in this case. The performance may be worse though because writing 8 bits only will always merge into the full rax register value, ie the high 56 bits are unchanged. Writing to eax means that the high 56 bits get written as well (24 bits data, 32 bits zero-extended as writing eax always zero-extends to rax). This can be better for performance. However, even better is movzx (not sure about AT&T syntax's name) because you will only load 8 bits of memory. This can even be more correct at a page's end (avoid a fault).

@SepRoland I am not sure I follow the concern. Wouldn't your solution with movzbl work if and only if movb did (i.e. one read gets the right byte from memory if and only if the other does)? Perhaps my confusion arises from not knowing what "partial registers" means here.

@ecm Fascinating, my question arose because I naively thought movb would be better for performance--so I am surprised (though I understand per your justification) that the thinking around performance was good, just in the opposite direction! I do not know movzx though. Is this movzbl perhaps?

@SepRoland movsbl would be more appropriate, given that char is a signed type.

x86-64 is little-endian. There are no additional modes to consider.

@EE18 Yes, from Sep Roland's answer I take it that movzx eax, byte [rdi] would be called movzbl (%rdi), %eax in AT&T syntax. It is called movzx in Intel syntax.

macOS with Apple silicon comes with Rosetta 2.  That lets you at least run x86-64 machine code just like you could on an x86-64 Mac.  I'm not sure how well it supports single-step debugging, but I assume it's possible somehow.  At worst in an emulated VM (e.g. running Linux.)  If you're learning x86-64 assembly, playing with it in a debugger and watching registers change as you single-step is a great way to learn and check your mental simulation of what you think something will do.

I've admittedly taken the (extreme?) step of buying a really cheap, used x86-64/Linux Mint box, so I fully intend on doing that :) @PeterCordes

You're right to be concerned about endianness for this kind of operation, but in this case, your alternative approach would fail on big-endian machines, not on little-endian ones.
x86 is little endian, which means the low-order eight bits of a 32-bit integer are stored in the first (lowest address) byte of that integer, so
movb (%rdi), %al     // Read low-order byte
movb %al, (%rsi)     // Store low-order byte

will do the truncation you want to do on x86.  But on a big-endian machine the equivalent operation would read the highest eight bits of the 32-bit integer. The m68k architecture, for instance, is big-endian; a correct version of your alternative approach, for that architecture, would be
move.b 3(%a1), %d0   // Read low-order byte
move.b %d0, (%a0)    // Store low-order byte

Without the 3 it would read the high-order byte of the int pointed to by register %a1.
The virtue of doing it the way CS:APP does it is that the same construct will work correctly on both big- and little-endian architectures.  Of course, if you're programming in assembly language you have to rewrite the code anyway to move the program to a different architecture, but it's one fewer thing to worry about while you're doing that.
Compiler-generated code will probably also do it the CS:APP way for related reasons: compilers usually do most of their work in an architecture independent "intermediate representation" and then translate that to assembly language. That translation is one of the most complex phases of an industrial grade compiler, for reasons beyond the scope of this answer; every simplifying assumption that doesn't make the generated code worse will be applied to make it easier to write.

Awesome, thanks so much for the answer, zwol. I was indeed mixing up my endiannesses here. One last question: what can we say about why the CS:APP method is endianness-independent? Is this because endianness is a "memory-only notion" and that, once data is in our registers, talking about the low-order bytes is unambiguous?

@EE18 Yes, that's one way to interpret this.

Super, thanks very much @fuz !

There’s almost no difference between using movl and movb here.
If the address used to load is unaligned and falls on a page boundary, then movl could be slower than using movb.
On the other hand, if the source is potentially a common sub expression, then movl provides access to the full value and the truncated value, whereas the other only provides access to the truncated value.
It is hard to imagine how endianess comes into play here on x86 platforms.  If for some reason you move to a big endian platform there will be different code — like the equivalent of movb al, 3(rsi) (the movl version will work unmodified.)

Thanks very much for this very helpful answer. To be honest, I didn't know x86 was definitively little-endian. I had thought that this was an aspect of processor mode which one could toggle, but I guess not.

You can toggle it for some processors. x86 has always been strictly little endian, but your Apple Silicon machine might be toggle-able; if I remember correctly that's an optional feature of the ARM architecture and I don't know if Apple decided to include it.
